# An audio device visibility control in Windows

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have 3'rd party application that depends on system audio. Unfortunately if fails handling scenario of reconnecting output audio device.

Specifically it fails when user plugs-out and plugs-in system LINE-OUT. At such scenario: "Speakers" output device disappears and shows up again (picture below)

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq0kX.png)

I was thinking that mayby there is a way to set this device allways enabled? I have some experience with Linux Audio programming and 'device' ==  "sound card" that is allways present in the system. I was a little bit surprised seeing 'device' disappearing when 'external device' is uplugged. Is there any way to keep available sound cards for that application allways available? (as it is accually now under the hood)

Comment: When you plug something into line-out, realtek might be changing your output device to that jack.  If you told us what app, that might help but "3rd party" does not.  What happens if the plug in is headphones to that jack?  Does the output switch between your speakers to the headphones (in other applications)?

Comment: Speakers connected = "Realtek Audio available" and LINE OUT Connected = "Realtek Audio available". Other applications handle line-out reconnection cleanly. Application name would't help it's not any of internet-avaiable product used by many members of this community.

Comment: Good luck.  If it is a commercial application, then you should be able to get support for it.

Comment: There is a support, but long response time. I need quick solution for now.